# How do Java classes get information from the Entry class?

Tags: java, oop

So lets say that in my entry point class (i.e the class which runs when the program starts (which has the `public static void main(String args[])` function). In that class I have this variable:

```
private ArrayList<String> myData=new ArrayList<String>();
```

This class instantiates another class, which needs to have access to the `myData` member of the entry point class. How can it retrieve this arraylist?

Edit: To clarify, in the `main()` method I could do this:

```
SomeOtherClass myClass=new SomeOtherClass();
```

and then I could do:

```
myClass.someMethod();
```

however, in the `myClass` object, how could I perform a method/retrieve something from the  entry class, which instantiated the `myClass` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your entry point is still static when it calls some other class, but your ArrayList is a member of an *instance* of it. You need to move out of the static world and into instances.

I'd refactor your main method into a private construtor, and put in a new main() which launches it as a new instance.

Note that this code is very rough, but it should serve to illustrate what you need to do.

```
public class EntryPoint {
    private ArrayList<String> myData=new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        EntryPoint ep = new EntryPoint();
        ep.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Populate myData perhaps?

        SomeOtherClass myClass=new SomeOtherClass();
        myClass.someMethod( this );
    }

    public List<String> getMyData() {
        return myData;
    }
}   

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void someMethod( EntryPoint entry ) {
        List<String> data = entry.getMyData();
        // do stuff with data..!
    }
}
```

Comment: I would generally avoid calling someMethod() in the constructor of EntryPoint, personally. Maybe add a doWork() method or something?

Comment: Well yes. I did say it was rough!

Comment: Actually you cannot safely pass "this" from a constroctor as the object has not been fully created yet.  This can lead to hard to track down bugs.  It _might_ work in this case but there are many other cases where it is broken.

Comment: Well yes. I did say it was rough! I've added an init() method though. Thanks.

Comment: much better.   we once spent the better part of a week tracking something down because of using "this" from a constructor (nasty threading bug).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to give the class you instantiate access to `myData` would be to pass it into the constructor when it is created.

Then, in your constructor, you can save the `ArrayList` into a member variable of the class.

For example, your object constructor will look like:

```
private ArrayList<String> myData;

public YourObjConstructor(ArrayList<String> data){
    myData = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class containing `main()` is just an ordinary class. In your case, you'd have to make `myData` `public` and possibly `static` (or, of course, add an accessor). Just like you'd do with any other class.

You could also pass an `Entry` object to the other class, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Entry entry = new Entry();
    SomeOtherClass myClass=new SomeOtherClass(entry);
    // continue as before
}
```

Comment: Yep. The question is why the ArrayList is in the entry class if it's being used somewhere else, but I'm not addressing that.